# C# writing a program that input of 2 numbers (a and b),gives an output of the sum of squares in between

Tags: c#

I`m quite new to the whole programming world.
And i started studying C#

i got the following exersice to do:

> Write a program that upon the input of 2 numbers (a and b), u receive
>   an output of the sum of squares in between.
>
> I.e. - The program receives a and b where `b > a` and calculates `a^2
>   + (a+1)^2 + (a+2)^2 + ... + (b-1)^2 + b^2.`
>
> E.g. - If `a = 3` and `b = 6`, the output would be 86, since `3^2 +
>   4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 = 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 = 86`

But i don't have any idea where do i even begin.
I`m guessing i need some sort of loop within a loop maybe?

Comment: I think you're interpreting the question wrong, I read it as, you get, say 3 and 10, the squares are 4 (2 squared) and 9 (3 squared) and you return the sum of those.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Arthur. Could you provide some code sample that you have already tried and which didn't worked, please?

Comment: Hint: you'll need a single loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use for loop for this. Please see below, if that helps-

```
        int i, j, k;
        int value=0;            
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the fist number ");
        i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number ");
        j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (i > j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second number should be greater then First");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }


        for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {

            value += k * k;

        }

        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hey,thanks a lot for the help. seems like it works. the only issue is that if i input the i int as the bigger number i get the whole if section. but the env exit just exists from the program and doesn`t continue.

Comment: @ArthurPinhas Refer to Rufus' reply to me below. If i is bigger than j just swap the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a method that takes in two integers and returns a double is a good place to start (returning a double allows you to specify a wider range of numbers without getting inaccurate results):

```
public static double GetSumOfSquaresBetween(int first, int second)
{
}
```

Then you could implement the body by creating a loop that goes from the lowest number to the highest number, adding the square of the current number to a result, and then returning that result at the end.

Here's a Linq example that would most likely not be acceptable for this assignment but gives you the idea:

```
public static double GetSumOfSquaresBetween(int first, int second)
{
    return Enumerable
        .Range(Math.Min(first, second), Math.Abs(first - second) + 1)
        .Select(number => Math.Pow(number, 2))
        .Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int a, b, sum = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the fist number ");
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number ");
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  if (a<b){

    for (int x = a+1; x < b; x++)
    {

        sum += x * x;

    }
     Console.WriteLine(sum);
  }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input!");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

A for loop should do it.

```
double nTotal = 0;

for (int a = 3; a <= 6; a++)
{
    nTotal += Math.Pow(a, 2);
}
```

Comment: This loop will either never start or never finish.

Comment: Assuming you've declared the variables why not?

Comment: you need < , not >

Comment: because if first number is greater than the second number and you keep adding one to it, the condition will always be true. if it's not greater than the second number, then it will never run.

Comment: @pm100 I was thinking it should be == shouldn't it?

Comment: the second clause in a for loop is 'keep going while this is true'. You will go nowhere with ==

Comment: @Rufus Fair enough.